# Adjusting the paragraph margin in subsection

Tags: sectioning, paragraphs

It might be a simple yet a silly question but it keeps bugging me for days. Base on my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % changes the margin
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}.}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontsize{11}{.5em}\bfseries}{\thesection}{.5em}
    {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\fontsize{11}{.5em}\selectfont}{\thesubsection}{.5em}
    {}
\titlespacing % starred version: first paragraph is not indented
{\subsection} % <command>
{1em} % <left>
{.4em} % <before-sep>
{.3em} % <after-sep>

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Subsection One}
    \begin{itemize}  [leftmargin=1.3cm,topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
        \item some item here and there
        \item some item here and there
    \end{itemize}

\subsection{Subsection Two}
\setlength\parindent{.85cm} \blindtext

\end{document}
```

And it resulted in this picture [image: Output Result]

My question is, how can I adjust the paragraph margin parallel with the subsection number? and **not** the section number?

Comment: Welcome! What exactly should be aligned with what? Note that you really do NOT want to use dimensions with no stretch in your heading definitions for vertical spaces, as this will reduce TeX's ability to find good places to break pages.

Comment: Put it simple, my intention was to create left margin on the second subsection paragraph so it will inline with the subsection numbering, instead of section numbering

Comment: paragraphs left border is correct, but you should redefine `\section{...}` style that it can protrude into left margin. solutions for this you can find on the site. try to change question tag to `section` and `styles`.

Comment: @Zarko sadly as a newbie I do not have enough "reputation" to put {section} and {styles} in tag (it requires +300)

Comment: So, say, the left of the 'I' in 'Introduction' should be aligned with the left of the '2' in the second subsection? Or the left of 'Lorem' should be aligned with the left of the '2'? Or ...?

Comment: It’s already been answered by @bernard, it actually just to align the second line in the paragraph with the number “2” in the second subsection

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you want? It all relies on the `\llap` command, which inserts its argument to the  left of the current point on the line without moving the latter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} % changes the margin
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand\thesection{\Alph{section}.}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}.}
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontsize{11}{.5em}\bfseries}{\llap{\thesection\hskip0.67em}}{0em}
    {}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\fontsize{11}{.5em}\selectfont}{\thesubsection}{.5em}
    {}
\titlespacing % starred version: first paragraph is not indented
{\subsection} % <command>
{0em} % <left>
{.4em} % <before-sep>
{.3em} % <after-sep>

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\subsection{Subsection One}
    \begin{itemize} [leftmargin=1.3cm,topsep=0pt,itemsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt]
        \item some item here and there
        \item some item here and there
    \end{itemize}

\subsection{Subsection Two}
\setlength\parindent{.85cm} \blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]